# ognl.MethodFailedException: Method failed for object [java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:([Ljava.lang.String;)]

Tags: struts2, ognl

I have a userCreateDate Field, When I Add the data for the first time, it gets inserted into resp. table,but when I try to update the same record by onClick of Javascript and setting the value to the respective textfields, it gives **Invalid field value for field "userTypeEntity.userCreatedDate".** and the date field value is coming null in validate() method.
Can you help me get out of this error.
My JSP is:

```
<table width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;" border="0" bordercolor="#006699" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <s:hidden id="id" name="userGroupEntity.userGroupId"/>
                    <s:textfield id="name" name="userGroupEntity.userGroupName"  key="label.groupName" maxlength="15" size="30" required="true" labelSeparator=""/>
                    <s:textfield id="desc" name="userGroupEntity.userGroupDesc"  key="label.groupDesc" maxlength="20" size="30" required="true" labelSeparator=""/>
                    <s:textfield id="cdate" name="userGroupEntity.userCreatedDate" key="label.CreatedDt" size="30" readonly="true" cssStyle="background-color:#E7EBDD;" labelSeparator=""/>
                    <s:textfield id="mdate" name="userGroupEntity.userModifiedDate" key="label.ModifiedDt" size="30" readonly="true" cssStyle="background-color:#E7EBDD;" labelSeparator=""/>
                    <s:radio     id="status" name="userGroupEntity.userActive"  key="label.status" list="userGroupStatus" required="true" labelSeparator=""/>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="100%" align="center"><hr></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="100%" align="center">
                        <s:submit id="save"  theme="simple" name="save" key="label.save"/>
                        <s:reset  id="reset" theme="simple" name="reset" key="label.reset"/>
                        <s:a href="userGroupView">
                            <img border="0" src='<s:url value="/images/b_cancel.gif"></s:url>' width="50" height="20" alt="Go to User Group Master">
                        </s:a>                      
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="100%">
                        <s:if test="hasActionMessages()"><div style="color:red;"><s:actionmessage/></div></s:if>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
<s:if test="{groupList.size() != 0}">
                <s:iterator value="groupList" var="group">
                    <tr>
                        <td><s:property value="userGroupName"/></td>
                        <td><s:property value="userGroupDesc"/></td>
                        <td><s:property value="userCreatedDate"/></td>
                        <td><s:property value="userModifiedDate"/></td>
                        <td align="center"><b><a href="#" onclick="javascript:userGroupEdit('edit','${userGroupId}','${userGroupName}','${userGroupDesc}','${userCreatedDate}','${userModifiedDate}');">Edit</a></b>
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;<b><a href="#" onclick="javascript:userGroupDelete('userGroupDelete.action?groupId=${userGroupId}');">Delete</a></b>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </s:iterator>
            </s:if>
```

And My Action Class is:

```
public class UserGroupAction extends ActionSupport implements Preparable{
    private static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(UserGroupAction.class);
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String result;
    private UserGroupEntity userGroupEntity;
    private Map<String, String> userGroupStatus;
    private List<UserGroupEntity> groupList;
    private int userSaveStatus;
    private int groupId; 
        public String userGroupSave() throws Exception{
            log.info("...In UserGroupAction.userGroupSave...");
    //      int userSaveStatus = 1;
            try {
                int groupId = userGroupEntity.getUserGroupId();
                System.out.println("Group Id: "+groupId);
                System.out.println("Group Name: "+userGroupEntity.getUserGroupName());
                if(groupId == 0){
                    userSaveStatus = UserGroupController.userGroupSave(userGroupEntity);
                    System.out.println("userSaveStatus: "+userSaveStatus);
                    if(userSaveStatus == 1 ){
                        addActionMessage("Group Added Successfully.");
                        result = SUCCESS;
                    }else{
                        addActionMessage("Group Already Exists.");
                        result = SUCCESS;
                    }
                }else{
                    userSaveStatus = UserGroupController.userGroupSave(userGroupEntity,groupId);
                    System.out.println("userSaveStatus: "+userSaveStatus);
                    if(userSaveStatus == 1 ){
                        addActionMessage("Group Updated Successfully.");
                        result = SUCCESS;
                    }else{
                        addActionMessage("Group Already Exists.");
                        result = SUCCESS;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("...In Catch of UserGroupAction.execute ...");
                result = ERROR;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }

    @Override
        public void validate(){
            System.out.println("...In UserGroupAction.validate ...");
            if(isEmpty(userGroupEntity.getUserGroupName())){
                addFieldError("userGroupEntity.userGroupName", "Group name can't be empty.");
            }

            if(isEmpty(userGroupEntity.getUserGroupDesc())){
                addFieldError("userGroupEntity.userGroupDesc", "Group description can't be empty.");
            }
            if(isEmpty(userGroupEntity.getUserActive())){
                addFieldError("userGroupEntity.userActive", "Please select status.");
            }

            //System.out.println("Create Date:: "+userGroupEntity.getUserCreatedDate());
        }
}
```

Here all other testField values are coming in action, but date field values are coming null... Please Help. Am Stucked here...

My Javascript is:

```
function userGroupEdit(flag,id,name,desc,cdate,mdate){
    alert(flag+id+name+desc+cdate+mdate);
    if(flag=='edit'){
        document.getElementById("id").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("id").value=parseInt(id);
        document.getElementById("name").value=name;
        document.getElementById("desc").value=desc;
        document.getElementById("cdate").value=cdate;
        document.getElementById("mdate").value=mdate;
        document.getElementById("statusY").checked=true;

    }else{
        //document.getElementById("save").style.display="block";
    }
    //window.location = url;//"${pageContext.request.contextPath}/"+url;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you have validation errors, could you post your `validation.xml`.

Comment: Thanx Roman for your response. But I do not want to validate this field. This date textfield is filled by onClick of edit link. and I am not using validation.xml, I am using annotations. Help me...

Comment: Post JSP and action code.

Comment: I atttached my JSP and Action Class

Comment: Post your javascript.

Comment: You have posted `userTypeEntity.userCreatedDate` but there's no such field.

Comment: Hi Raman, It is there. Plz chk properly.

Comment: Hi Aleksandr, the thing is date fields are not mandatory fields and readonly fields, so not added in validate() method to validate these. If I validate these fields to check null and reset these with any (new Date) object, this error is not coming. But date of these fields are coming from DB, so I should not change it to (new Date).... Guys help me on this Struts2 parts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution: In Javascript I formatted the date as

```
function setDateFormat(strDate){
    //strDate '2014-06-18'      
     //alert(strDate.length);
    if(strDate!=''){
        var y,m,d;
        y = strDate.substring(0,4);//alert(y);
        m = strDate.substring(5,7);//alert(m);
        d = strDate.substring(8,10);//alert(d);
        var newDate = m+"/"+d+"/"+y;
        //alert(newDate);
        return newDate;
    }else{
        if(typeof(strDate) == 'string'){
            newDate = '';
            return newDate;
        }
    }
}
```

These date fields are now getting persisted in DB and there is no Struts2 field message like **Invalid field value for field** from validate method.